# Integrate the Twitter in IOS sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, twitter

In my app, I want to get the list of following/follower friends from the twitter.

Right now, **i just able to fetch the name & id of the followers but not the followings.**

My code is as follow:

```
-(void) getTwitterFriendsIDListForThisAccount{

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json"];

    NSDictionary *p = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:myAccount.username, @"screen_name", nil];

    TWRequest *twitterRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:url parameters:p requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];

    [twitterRequest setAccount:myAccount];
    [twitterRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResposnse, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error) {

         }
         NSError *jsonError = nil;
         // Convert the response into a dictionary
         NSDictionary *twitterFriends = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&jsonError];

         NSArray *IDlist = [twitterFriends objectForKey:@"ids"];

         NSLog(@"response value is: %@", IDlist);
}
```

**How can I get the following list ids??** and also the email_ids, if possible.

**Sometimes it shows the error for the migration. How to migrate from 1.0 to 1.1?**

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the best solution : Just download Sharekit and follow the step

ShareKit
[ShareKit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit)

and see SHKTwitter.h and SHKTwitter.m file you can get it.

its easy